# How to change object structure with pure JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am struggling with changing the structure of object.
I want to convert object from this:

```
var data = {
  "a1.img": 'img1',
  "a1.href": 'href1',
  "a2.img": 'img2',
  "a2.href": 'href2',
  "a3.img": 'img3',
  "a3.href" : 'href3'
};
```

Into this:

```
var data = {
  "a1":{    
    "img": "img1",
    "href": "href1" 
  },
  "a2":{    
    "img": "img2",
    "href": "href2" 
  },
  "a3":{    
    "img": "img3",
    "href": "href3"
  }
}
```

My solution is not working properly and I don't know how to fix it. My solution:

```js
var data = {
  "a1.img": 'img1',
  "a1.href": 'href1',
  "a2.img": 'img2',
  "a2.href": 'href2',
  "a3.img": 'img3',
  "a3.href": 'href3'
};

var newData = {};
for (var key in data) {
  newData[key.split('.')[0]] = {};
  for (var i in data) {
    newData[key.split('.')[0]][i.split('.')[1]] = data[key]
  }
}

console.log(newData)
```

Please help.

Comment: just replace `-` in the duplicate target with `.` as separator.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find similar solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `Array#reduce` to loop over the original array and append the properties to the accumulator.

```js
var data = {
  "a1.img": 'img1',
  "a1.href": 'href1',
  "a2.img": 'img2',
  "a2.href": 'href2',
  "a3.img": 'img3',
  "a3.href" : 'href3'
};

var res = Object.entries(data).reduce((a, [k,v]) => {
  var [key, prop] = k.split('.');
  
  if (!a[key]) {
    a[key] = {};
  }
  
  a[key][prop] = v;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution looks really awesome and easy. Now I will repeat everything step by step to understand it completely! I must learn how to work with `reduce` method.

Comment: this proposal works only for strings with a single dot.

Comment: @NinaScholz -- Yeah, that's true. This isn't scalable. The answer of marked duplicate question is pretty much what OP wants to do.